# How to apply formatting to just one cell in Apache Poi in Spring Boot with Java

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am currently formatting a date in a cell, but this formatting is leaking to other cells, transforming some cells into dates, I wanted to know how to format only a single cell without affecting the others.

[image]

The Date formatting would only be in my last column I due date, but as in the image above it formatted my column C file 3 something that should not happen

I followed this tutorial but it doesn't solve my problem because the date formatting is going to other fields
[Link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-apache-poi-date-format)

```
       `
              
              import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx;
              import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
              import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
              import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

              import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
              import java.io.IOException;
              import java.util.List;

              public class xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx {

              @Autowired
              private xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDTO xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDTO;



             public static void xxxxxxxx(HttpServletResponse response,    List<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDTO> xxxxxxx) {
             try(Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()){
              Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("xxxxxx a xxxxxx");

             CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();




            cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);


            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("file");
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellValue("file1");
            cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


            Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue("file2");
            cell2.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            Cell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
            cell3.setCellValue("file3");
            cell3.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            Cell cell4 = row.createCell(4);
            cell4.setCellValue("file4");
            cell4.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            Cell cell5 = row.createCell(5);
            cell5.setCellValue("file5");
            cell5.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


            Cell cell6 = row.createCell(6);
            cell6.setCellValue("file6");
            cell6.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


            Cell cell7 = row.createCell(7);
            cell7.setCellValue("file7");
            cell7.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


            Cell cell8 = row.createCell(8);
            cell8.setCellValue("file8");
            cell8.setCellStyle(cellStyle);







            int rowNum = 1;
            for (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDTO integ : xxxx) {
            Row intDataRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);

            Cell empCell = intDataRow.createCell(0);
            empCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            empCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile());

            Cell filNameCell = intDataRow.createCell(1);
            filNameCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            filNameCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile1());

            Cell cdCell = intDataRow.createCell(2);
            cdCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            cdCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile2());

            Cell coCell = intDataRow.createCell(3);
            coCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            coCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile3());

            Cell poCell = intDataRow.createCell(4);
            poCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            poCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile4());

            Cell tiCell = intDataRow.createCell(5);
            tiCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            tiCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile5());


            Cell saCell = intDataRow.createCell(6);
            saCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            saCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile6());

            Cell comCell = intDataRow.createCell(7);
            comCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            comCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile7());


            Cell venCell = intDataRow.createCell(8);
            venCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            venCell.setCellValue(integ.getFile8());
            cellStyle.setDataFormat((short) 14);
            


        }


        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }


  }`
```

Comment: Have two cell styles, one for your "normal" cells, and a different one for you date cells, then take care about which one you apply where?

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood how to do it, I created one
`CellStyle cellStyleData = workbook.createCellStyle();` separated and I replaced the cell8 one and what I needed came, which was just her.